# How do you apply the filters from a dict which contains both string and list values in django?

Tags: python, django, search, filter, django-queryset

I have dict - filters like this:

```
    "filter1": "string",
    "filter2": [
      "A","B"
    ],
    "filter3": "string",
    "filter4": [
      "C","D"
    ],
  }
```

where filter1,filter2,filter3 filter4 are some fields in my model.

This `query_set = query_set.filter(**filters)` works fine for all the filters whose type is not list,

But I want to filter the query_set as cleanly as possible, 
How do you apply the filters using a dict which contains both string and list values?

PS: I know about __in & know I can do something like

```
filter2_list = filters.get(filter2) 
if filter2_list:
   query_set = query_set.filter(filter2__in=filter2_list)
```

But, 
1. I don't want to use if-else statements
2. I want to have dynamic variables in the filters arguments and not hardcore ones like filter2__in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not a very clean way by any means, but you can get away by just iterating through your filters once, checking if it's a list or not.

```
new_filters = {}
for key,value in f.items():
     new_filters[f"{key}__in" if isinstance(value,list) else key] = value
```

```
query_set = query_set.filter(**new_filters)
```